# Kafka message not always consumed

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have issue with consuming Kafka messages (by spring boot app running via Kubernetes)
The issue occurs inconsistent i.e. sometimes messages consumed and sometimes no

Consumer configured with following settings :

```
Map<String, Object> consumerConfig = new HashMap<>(config);
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, BytesDeserializer.class);
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, ByteArrayDeserializer.class);
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_COMMIT_INTERVAL_MS_CONFIG, 2000);
consumerConfig.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, String.format("GROUP_ID.{%s}", "myTopicName"));
consumerConfig.put(JsonDeserializer.TRUSTED_PACKAGES, "*");
```

The topic configuration :

```
Name   myTopicName
Partitions   5
cleanup.policy  delete
max.message.bytes  2097164
retention.bytes -1
retention.ms 604800000
```

What can be possible reasons , which param should be rechechecked ?
I know there were asked similar questions before , but did not found the answer
Any help will valuable
Thanks in advance